# Change magento header cart price currency symbol from $ to Rs

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7

I want to change the magento header cart price currency symbol from **$** to **Rs.** in my dummy application. Please have a look on my dummy installation: http://questoons.com/ojp/index.php/

You can see on site, all items prices are in **Rs.** ( Indian rupee format ) but the cart price ( look on header **total price $0.00** ) is in **$**. I want to display it like **total price Rs. 0.00**

Please guide how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin panel:

**system>configuration>general>currency setup>currency options>change Base currency, default display currency**

If you have already done that than in admin panel goto:

**system>configuration>developer>debug>template path hints**, set it to **'yes'**.

Than refresh your website homepage. You'll be able to see the path to your template file. Go there, remove Dollar '$' symbol and add 'Rs.'.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Madzacky. Path system>configuration>developer>debug>template path hints does not exist in my installation. I am using Magento 1.7. What to do next, please advice.

Comment: I am using Magento 1.7 too my friend, but there has to be this option. From system menu, there probably will be last menu item configuration, select it, than from left sidebar select the last option developer, than debug, make sure you have selected your current store from drop down box above left side bar.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use English language in magento.**

> Open lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml

find

> < currency type="INR" >

Add code 
:

> < symbol>Rs< /symbol>

before close < /currency>

**and set your default and base currency**

Go:

> system > configuration > general > currency setup > currency options > change
>   Base currency,  ,default display currency, allowed currency

select indian rupee.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Ravi but this solution did not work in my case. What to do now?